# A Burning Puzzl .

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

***Final Answer*** ✅
[image]
***Can you solve this burning puzzl...?***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle seems to be...

> **GAME OF THRONES**

First, we must solve each of the 8 rebuses. I believe these work out as:

> 1. **EXTER** = EX + TERRACE - RACE
>
>  2. **SHELOCK** = SHE (a girl) + LOCK
>
>  3. **FLSH** = FL (Florida) + SHH - H
>
>  4. **LUKE AGE** = L + UK + E (East) + AGE (the 18+ symbol)
>
>  5. **ORPHN** = OR ([||](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)) + PH (the pH of pure water is 7) + N (North)
>
>  6. **BEAKING BAD** = BEAK IN G + BALD - L (50 in Roman numerals)
>
>  7. **PEAK BLINDERS** = PEAK + BLENDERS with the 'LE' changed to 'LI'
>
>  8. **BLINDPOT** = BLIND POT (it has no eyes)

Hopefully, you will have noticed as we solved these that...

> ...these are all the names of **TV drama shows missing a letter**:
>
>  [**D**EXTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_(TV_series)), [SHE**R**LOCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_(TV_series)), [(the) FL**A**SH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flash_(2014_TV_series)), [LUKE **C**AGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Cage_(TV_series)), [(the) ORPH**A**N](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21833232/), [B**R**EAKING BAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad), [PEAK**Y** BLINDERS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaky_Blinders_(TV_series)), [BLIND**S**POT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindspot_(TV_series)).
>
>  (Note that this 'missing letter' mechanism is indicated in the title of this 'Puzzl'...)

On to the final clue then...

> Our 8 missing letters taken in order spell **DRACARYS**. Coupled with the fire icon this is the 8-letter command given by the Targaryens in [Game of Thrones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones) whenever they want their dragons to breathe fire. Since the final answer has enumeration (4,2,7) (count the dashes) and the context of the puzzle is TV dramas, it seems likely to me that the intended final answer of this 'burning' puzzle is **GAME OF THRONES** as a result.

Comment: Great Job! Very well put up. Also, r13(Gvgyr vf zvffvat n yrggre nf jryy.) But may be you didn't feel the need haha! Well done again !! :)

Comment: @Techidiot Indeed, I omitted that as I thought it was fairly self-evident but I can add a mention of it for completeness :)